# Weird Behaviour of my PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu-usage

I have windows 7 installed in my PC. Suddenly, the CPU Performance has reached above 70% with no task running where as when I run any application(such as Explorer.exe) the CPU usage reaches to 100%. 
Please suggest me, Why is this?

Comment: Right click the task bar and choose Task Manager, go to the processes tab, then click the CPU column heading.  This should show the process using the most CPU.

Answer (score 0):

When running Task Manager, sometimes you need to click on the button at the bottom of the Task Manager screen in order to see all process and how much processor they use. The button is labeled "Show Processes From All Users".

Microsoft Windows 7 runs the Malicious Software Removal Tool from time-to-time and I have found it can hog the processor.

Good Luck.